# Package RCL and Inf

Tags: common-lisp

this will be a difficult question to answer, I contacted the author but still no replies I'll give it a shot here:
In the package RCL (http://common-lisp.net/project/rcl/) examples:

```
(in-package :rcl)
(r-init)

(r "/" 1 5)
RCL> 0.2d0

(r "print" (r% "/" 1 5))
RCL> ;R# [1] 0.2
0.2d0
```

The above is ok, but

```
(r "/" 1 0)
RCL>> #<a FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW>
```

broken

```
(r "print" (r% "/" 1 0))
RCL>> ;R# [1] Inf
#<a FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW>
```

broken

or `(r "log" 0)`

How to get around this so that when R gets to an inf value my Lisp doesn't break but just gives a message that an inf value is computed; The above is a simple example but there are times when we have during a statistical procedure divisions by zero that nevertheless do not invalidate the results and R returns a final value (like during optimization), but this unfortunately crashes while using RCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got the answer from the author I post here:
support for IEEE floating-point infinities is platform-dependent. The following Lisps work, at least on this system (MacOSX):

**SBCL**

```
R> (r "/" 1 0)
.SB-EXT:DOUBLE-FLOAT-POSITIVE-INFINITY
R> (r "log" 0)
.SB-EXT:DOUBLE-FLOAT-NEGATIVE-INFINITY
```

**Allegro CL**

```
R> (r "/" 1 0)
.EXCL:*INFINITY-DOUBLE*
R> (r "log" 0)
.EXCL:*NEGATIVE-INFINITY-DOUBLE*
```

**LispWorks**

```
R> (r "/" 1 0)
+1D++0 #| +1D++0 is double-float plus-infinity
R> (r "log" 0)
-1D++0 #| -1D++0 is double-float minus-infinity
```

**CMUCL** doesn't (X86:SIGFPE-HANDLER, no exceptions enabled), but I think this can be fixed (http://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/extensions.html#float-traps).

**ECL** is the last one that I tried, and it's apparently the one you use (I got the same `FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW` exception). It seems that it also allows to disable overflow checks using `SI:TRAP-FPE`, this might be what you need (the following example is taken from http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=386):

```
(let* ((bits (si::trap-fpe 'last nil)))
   (prog1 (/ 1.0 0.0)
     (si::trap-fpe bits t)))
.SI:SINGLE-FLOAT-POSITIVE-INFINITY
```

**Also this works in general**:

```
(handler-case (r "/" 2 0)
  (floating-point-overflow () nil))
```

Comment: Also this works in general: 
(handler-case  (r "/" 2 0)
        (floating-point-overflow () nil))